# Wiremock showing zero code coverage even-though Junit is green

Tags: java, junit, junit5, wiremock

BaseControllerTest:

```
private static int port;
public static String hostUrl;
protected static WireMockServer wireMockServer;
protected static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public static RestTemplate restTemplate;
public static final String HOST = "localhost";  
  

@Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();    
@BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig().dynamicPort());
        wireMockServer.start();
        port = wireMockServer.port();
        WireMock.configureFor(HOST, port);
        hostUrl = "http://" + HOST + ":" + port;
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void destroy() {
        wireMockServer.stop();
    }
```

DummyResourceTest extends BaseControllerTest:

```
 @Test
public void testScenario1WithSuccess() throws JAXBException {
    stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo(END_POINT))
            .withHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, equalTo(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, equalTo(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .withHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, equalTo(TEST_SERVICE_TOKEN))
            .withRequestBody(containing(TEST_FIELD_1))
            .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200)
                    .withHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .withBody(readJsonFile("Sample_Response.json"))));

    RequestObject request = new RequestObject();
    request.setField1("111");

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    httpHeaders.add(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON);
    httpHeaders.set(AppConstants.AUTHORIZATION,  TEST_SERVICE_TOKEN);
    HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request, httpHeaders);


    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity =  restTemplate.exchange(END_POINT,
            HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
            String.class);

    assertNotNull(responseEntity);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(),responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue());
    
}
```

Test runs properly and its green as well. But it's showing zero code coverage (in IntelliJ) for that Dummy Controller/resource class.
[image]

Anything I am missing here?

Comment: one line of 510 covered? I would agree that 1 is less than 1% of 510. a unit test being green means nothing. assert(true); will be green as well, doesn't mean it adds up to code or scenario coverage

Comment: I tried adding assert condition for multipole fields from response object but still coverage is showing zero. Basically my question is that why lines not getting covered with above Junit? what is missing.

Comment: adding asserts for fields of the response doesn't change anything about coverage, why should it? and, how are we to know? it's not like we know what you are testing.